# Spring JPA Query by Example returns no results

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring's JPA ExampleMatcher without success.

So far, I have:

```
    ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching()
            .withIgnoreNullValues()
            .withMatcher("surname",  match -> match.contains().ignoreCase());
    Person p = new Person();
    v.setSurname("Sm");
```

Hoping to match `Person` objects whose `surname` field contains the specified substring.

But I consistently get no results.

On looking up the query log,  can see why: at tries to match all the other fields too.

How can I get `ExampleMatcher` to ignore all other fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.withIgnorePaths()` to ignore primitive fields in `Person`.

Comment: can'g it ignore all paths except those for which matchers are defined? The list of matchers is not constant.

Comment: Could it be that you use primitive fields in `Person`? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45230155/1602555.

Comment: Yes, I do have primitive fields. I have swapped them for the primitive wrapper objects. That did the trick!